# How do I create and control by touch an infinite amount of UIImages?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimage

I need a sticker page where someone can keep bringing in as many stickers as they want and placing on the page. The user should be able to move any sticker. I can only move the sticker that was brought in, not the one that was saved that is brought in by the viewDidLoad method.

In touches began:

UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint location = [touch locationInView:touch.view];

```
if (location.x < image0.frame.size.width + image0.frame.origin.x && location.y < image0.frame.size.height + image0.frame.origin.y && location.x > image0.frame.origin.x && location.y > image0.frame.origin.y)
{
    [image0 removeFromSuperview];

    image0 = nil;
    image0 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(location.x - 25,location.y-25, 50, 50)];
    image0.image =[UIImage imageNamed:sticker.stickerFilePath];

    [self.view addSubview:image0];


}
```

In viewDidLoad, saved stickers from a class are being brought in:

stickerArray = [self loadStickerData];
    allStickers= [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:10];

```
    sticker=[self.childClass.stickerInfo objectAtIndex:0];

    float x = sticker.xLocationOfSticker, y = sticker.yLocationOfSticker, w =sticker.stickerWidth, h=sticker.stickerHeight;
    image0 =[[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(x,y,w,h)];
    image0.image=[UIImage imageNamed:sticker.stickerFilePath];
    [self.view addSubview:image0];
```

Comment: Please share the rest of your code. You reference variables that are not declared.

Comment: In regards to your title question, you can't make an "infinite" number of images in iOS, let alone control them.

Comment: you're best bet is to use a collection view or table view and take advantage of dequeueing